# Prestashop 1.7 include inline SVG in tpl file

Tags: svg, include, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to include an SVG inside my tpl file like this :

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("icon.svg"); ?>
```

Do you have some idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found a trick to include inline SVG file using the template system.

So I just create a folder named **_svg** in the **templates** folder of the theme. I renamed my **icon.svg** file to **icon.tpl** and I included it using the following code:

```
{include file="_svg/icon.tpl"}
```

If you need a variable (for exemple in a loop, use :

```
{include file="_svg/icon-{$var.value}.tpl"}
```

If you have other ideas, do not hesitate to let me know !

See you!

Comment: You can leave them as `.svg` and that will still work fine. Also, if you have inline css in your svg files, you should break any styling content within `{` and `}` to a new line to escape the smarty compiler https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.escaping.tpl

Comment: @squivo Thanks for talking about the escaping brace, it was the problem for me